# endian.h for floats

Tags: endianness

I am trying to read an unformatted binary file, that was written by a big endian machine. My machine is a 32bit little endian.
I already know how to swap bytes for different variable types, but it is a cumbersome work. I found this set of functions [endian.h](http://linux.die.net/man/3/endian) that handle integer swapping very easily.
I was wondering if there is something similar for floats or strings, or if I have to program it from scratch? Since they are handled differently for this endianness problem as integers.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think there is a standart header for swapping floats. You could take a look at http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/writing-endian-independent-code-in-c-r2091
which provides some helpful code.

As for strings, there is no need to do endian-swapping. Endianness is used to order the bytes of a variable. A string consists of a series of chars. Each char has only one Byte so there is nothing to swap.

Comment: Thanks, the article was already known to me, but I wanted to maybe simplify the work to do.